# Layers from SpatialLite Database are not displayed correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite

While working a lot with layers from spatialLite databases I face a returning bug in which layers from databases aren’t displayed correctly in the project. 
The error affects persisting layers as well as virtual layers, which are created by sql query. 
Layers are not displayed. Although related tables are shown correctly in the db-manager, related attribute tables are displayed empty, while the number of Objects is shown correctly.
[image]

The error suddenly appears at any time, while working on a project. Thus all layers from the database are affected, the only opportunity for fixing is to start a new project. 
While searching for solutions on the internet, zooming in and out may sometimes fix any displaying errors in virtual layers. While trying out still the problem remains.

Comment: Did you have recover the geometry columns of the layers created by sql query.

Comment: No, I didn't recover them. But the error seems to disappear as I reduce the number of virtuel layers in the project. Maybe it simply based on PC performance o?